# No module named 'torch' in Jupyter Notebook but it is installed (Mac OS)

Tags: macos, jupyter-notebook, importerror

So when I try to import torch in jupyter notebook it gives the error no module named 'torch'.

I created a conda environment named "Thesis" where I work in and install my packages.

When I try these commands in my terminal it says the package is installed (see three images below):

[torch1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wKlup.png)

[torch2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fOEaH.png)

[torch3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FM1Tq.png)

I tried many commands to install the package:

```
pip install torchvision
```

```
python3 -m pip install torchvision
```

```
conda install pytorch torchvision -c pytorch
```

I also tried installing the package directly in the jupyter notebook itself via:

```
import sys
!{sys.executable} -m pip install torchvision
```

It at least shows something but I got the following dependency error

[dependency error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJOq8.png)

I also created a kernel

```
ipython kernel install --name "thesis" --user
```

All did not help and I still receive the error in jupyter notebook.
Does somebody know how to resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem by downloading and activating virtualenv with:

```
python3 -m pip install virtualenv
virtualenv <my_env_name> 
source <my_env_name>/bin/activate
```

And getting the path in the jupyter notebook by:

```
import sys
print(sys.executable)
```

which outputs:

```
/Users/{username}/opt/anaconda3/bin/python
```

And installing the packages in the terminal via:

```
/Users/{username}/opt/anaconda3/bin/python -m pip install {package_name}
```